# $[\mathbb{F}:\mathbb{K}]=1$ if and only if $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{K}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

$\mathbb{F}$ is field extension of $\mathbb{K}$. I have to show $[\mathbb{F}:\mathbb{K}]=1$ if and only if $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{K}$.

Comment: you should show your  work otherwise you may get some downvotes !

Answer (score 5):

If $[\Bbb F : \Bbb K] = 1$, then as a vector space over $\Bbb K$, a basis for $\Bbb F$ has only *one* element.  But $1$ is always an element of the basis.  So $\{1 \}$ is the basis for $\Bbb F$ as a $\Bbb K$-vector space.

But if this is true, then each element in $\Bbb F$ can be written as $1 \cdot k$ for some $k \in \Bbb K$.  But then that means every element of $\Bbb F$ is in $\Bbb K$, so $\Bbb F \subseteq \Bbb K$.  And we know $\Bbb K \subseteq \Bbb F$, so we get $\Bbb F = \Bbb K$, as desired.

Comment: when you say $\mathbb F$=$\mathbb K$ you mean $\mathbb F$ is isomorph to $\mathbb K$?

Comment: @AaronMartinez We usually talk about fields being isomorphic if the underlying sets can't be compared, like, for example, a field of matrices and a field of numbers.  Elements in the underlying sets can't be compared, since matrices aren't numbers and numbers aren't matrices.  But we *can* compare elements in $\Bbb F$ and $\Bbb K$.  $\Bbb F$ being a field extension of $\Bbb K$ means $\Bbb K$ is a field, $\Bbb F$ is a field, and $\Bbb K \subseteq \Bbb F$.  So since $\Bbb K \subseteq \Bbb F$, it makes perfect sense to talk about equality, and the result is $\Bbb F= \Bbb K$.  Does that help?